# What is an isomorphism between $L:aX+bY=Z$ and $\Bbb P^1_K$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, projective-varieties, morphism

It is known that genus $0$ smooth curve over field $K$ with base point is isomorphic to $\Bbb P^1_K$ over $K$.

I want to understand this with a lot of examples.

For example, let $a,b\in K^\times$ and consider the line $L:aX+bY=Z\subset \Bbb P^2_K$.

How can I construct an isomorphism between $L:aX+bY=Z$ and $\Bbb P^1_K$ ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Projecting onto $X$ and $Y$ gives an isomorphism $L \to \mathbb P^1_K$, since $Z$ is uniquely determined by $X$ and $Y$.